# Uploading items to iCloud never ending (for weeks)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, data-transfer

Is there a way to relaunch the upload to iCloud Drive?

My Mac has been uploading severals files for weeks.

[image]
[image]

I already tried to relaunch the Finder without success using `killall Finder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happened to me as well, here is what I did:

1. Back up all items in the ***Documents*** and ***Desktop*** folders (or wherever you are backing up your files)
2. Open up ***System Preferences***
3. Click on ***iCloud***
4. Click on ***Options*** next to ***iCloud Drive***
5. If ***Desktop and Document Folders*** is disabled, enable it
6. If enabled, disable it.
7. Uncheck the ***Optimize Mac Storage*** and click ***Done***
8. Redo the opposite of steps 5-7 to re-enable iCloud
9. Move all ***Documents*** and ***Desktop*** items back to their respective area.

It is helpful to note if you are experiencing sync issues in any of the other categories in ***iCloud Drive***, try disabling them and then re-enabling them.

Answer (score 0):

I think for me it was my WhatsApp backup, I disabled WhatsApp under apps syncing to iCloud on my Mac and it stopped.

[image: Screenshot of 'Apps syncing to iCloud Drive' in the iCloud System Settings with apps turned off]